# web service page System.IndexOutOfRangeException

Tags: asp.net, asmx

```
public class GetAreaFromCity : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    [WebMethod]
    public GetAreaByCityId ClassForGetCIty(int City_Id)
    {
        string CS =ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["FOODINNConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spGetCityById",con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            SqlParameter parameter = new SqlParameter("@ID", City_Id);

            //To assiate this parameter object with cmd object
            cmd.Parameters.Add(parameter);
            GetAreaByCityId GETAreaByCityId =new GetAreaByCityId();
            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            //as WeakReference read data wewant ToString retrive Column value & then polute this property City_Id values
            while (reader.Read()){
                GETAreaByCityId.City_Id = Convert.ToInt32(reader["City_Id"]);
                GETAreaByCityId.Area_Id =     Convert.ToInt32(reader["Area_Id"]);

            }
            return GETAreaByCityId;

            //ToString return sql
        }
    }
}
```

that's my codes for service page

```
public class GetAreaByCityId
{
    public int Ca_Id {get;set; }
    public int City_Id { get; set; }
    public int Area_Id { get; set; }
}
```

that's the class for getting the Area by city

```
Create Proc [dbo].[spGetCityById]
@ID int 
as
Begin
Select Area_Id from 
CITIES_AREA where City_Id = @ID
End
GO
```

and above the database procedure which is data can be retrieve

> System.IndexOutOfRangeException: City_Id
>   at System.Data.ProviderBase.FieldNameLookup.GetOrdinal(String fieldName)
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.GetOrdinal(String name)
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_Item(String name)
>   at WebApplication1.GetAreaFromCity.ClassForGetCIty(Int32 City_Id) in            c:\Users\Mudassir\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\WebApplication1\WebAppli

the above error i dont know whats the problem

Comment: ASMX is a legacy technology, and should not be used for new development. WCF or ASP.NET Web API should be used for all new development of web service clients and servers. One hint: Microsoft has retired the [ASMX Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/threads) on MSDN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your stored procedure is returning only `Area_Id`.  Your code in the "while loop" `while (reader.Read()){` is attempting to read data from two columns:

- `City_Id`
- `Area_Id`

You could add the column `City_Id` to the result set for your stored procedure query, BUT you already have that value because you are passing it to the stored procedure as a parameter.

Easiest fix is probably to just change this line:

`GETAreaByCityId.City_Id = Convert.ToInt32(reader["City_Id"]);`

to this:

`GETAreaByCityId.City_Id = City_Id;`

Comment: I'm glad it worked!  When you get a chance **please mark my answer as 'accepted'** which will increase your Reputation by +2 and if you think this represents a 'good quality' answer then please also Upvote it.